# MapReduce chained job never ends

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to chain two jobs with the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.*` library, instead of the classic one, but when I execute my .jar file with Hadoop, it never ends, even if it produces the correct output that I expected.

I would like to use this library, and know how can I stop the execution when the second job is finished. Like I've used `job.waitForCompletion(true)`, and also like if I execute a .jar with only one job.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl;

public class Interest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(Interest.class);
        conf1.setJobName("Interest");
        conf1.setMapperClass(InterestMapperA.class);
        conf1.setReducerClass(InterestReducerA.class);
        conf1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf1.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf1, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf1, new Path("temp"));

        JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(Interest.class);
        conf2.setJobName("Interest");
        conf2.setMapperClass(InterestMapperB.class);
        conf2.setReducerClass(InterestReducerB.class);
        conf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf2, new Path("temp"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(args[1]));

        Job job1 = new Job(conf1);
        Job job2 = new Job(conf2);
        JobControl jbcntrl = new JobControl("jbcntrl");
        jbcntrl.addJob(job1);
        jbcntrl.addJob(job2);
        job2.addDependingJob(job1);
        jbcntrl.run();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue with the old library, infact the newest one haven't the property for manage the job dependency.